# Using group-helper with ember-app-kit : assertion fails

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-app-kit

I'm trying to use [Ember.js group-helper](https://github.com/emberjs/group-helper) with Ember App Kit.

Since `group` has no dash, `app/helpers/group.js` can't be resolved, so I'm loading the helper explicitly in `app.js`, as explained in [EAK docs](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/guides/using-modules.html).

***`app/helpers/group.js`***

```
export default function(option) {
  var data = options.data,
      fn   = options.fn,
      view = data.view,
      childView;

  childView = view.createChildView(Ember._MetamorphView, {
    context: Ember.get(view, 'context'),

    template: function(context, options) {
      options.data.insideGroup = true;
      return fn(context, options);
    }
  });

  view.appendChild(childView);
}
```

in ***`app.js`***

```
import GroupHelper from 'appkit/helpers/group';
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('group', GroupHelper);
```

in a template

```
<ul>
{{#group}}
  {{#each}}
    <li>{{prop1}} {{prop2}}</li>
  {{/each}}
{{/group}}
</ul>
```

I get an assertion failed :

```
registerBoundHelper-generated helpers do not support use with Handlebars blocks.
```

*(the app works fine without the group helper)*

I know the `group-helper` is experimental, but does that mean it's not working with current Ember release ?

If this is supposed to work, what am I missing ?

Edit after @Stakoov's comment:
I've updated from Ember 1.4.0-beta6 to 1.4.0 and I'm using Handlebars 1.3.0.

I've tried the EAK way, renaming `group` to `group-item` (since EAK resolver needs a dash).

***`app/helpers/group-item.js`***

```
export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function(options) {
  // (...snip...)
});
```

in the template :

```
<ul>
{{#group-item}}
  {{#each}}
    <li>{{prop1}}</li>
  {{/each}}
{{/group-item}}
</ul>
```

Still the same Assertion failed.

Comment: It seems that [this issue](https://github.com/emberjs/group-helper/issues/4) is somewhat related...   (newb limitation on number of links...)

Comment: "Currently requires Ember.js master." this is from read me. Are you use current release or canary?

Comment: I'm using Ember 1.4.0-beta.6 - I've tried updating to 1.4.0, but I get the same Assertion failed